# Saying for "Bomb proof"

Tags: idioms

In Spain, we normally use a saying when something always works well, although you try to break this one. The saying is ***"bomb proof"***.

I would like to know a similar saying in English.

For example:

I make a program and this passes all the tests that you try and you invent.
I could say "This is a bomb proof program".

Comment: We use that and *bullet proof*.

Comment: @StoneyB - And sometimes _idiot proof_, if we are talking about the ability to withstand inept users.

Comment: @J.R. True, but in my experience that one's chimerical. As Schiller said, "Against stupidity the gods themselves fight in vain."

Comment: to create software, not make it.  Software would not be said to be bomb-proof. And if in Spanish you mean: a pruebas de bombas, it's not exactly heard on every street corner nor is it applied to software necessarily.

Comment: *Create software* and *make software* are equally common in all the corpora I have available.  The problem in the OP's example isn't *make*, it's using *software* as a count noun.

Comment: @snailboat - I agree that _make_ is as good as _create_. My preferred verb, though, would be [_write_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=create+software%2Cmake+software%2Cwrite+software&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: "Iron Clad" is another option.

Comment: "bomb proof" has a specialized usage for people who work with horses, a horse who is "bomb proof" is so calm that he wouldn't be scared even if a bomb blew up right next to him--but it doesn't have anything to do with the horse not breaking in other (possibly literal) ways. We would use "bullet proof" for a horse who was immune to harm.

Comment: @Lambie Depends what the software is for. I'd bet the software that routes packets across the country is bomb-proof, as in, capable of adjusting in the case of a bomb destroying a router :)

Comment: @NicHartley Packets are automatically routed when they encounter an impediment. When a  packet can't get through on hop (server or server node), it switches to another, that's what packet switching is all about.  However, it has to be able to leave the client....and the server has been "bombed", it's moot.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, Anglophones use ***bullet proof*** as well as ***bomb proof***. Also note that regardless of whether the usage is literal or metaphoric, we usually write the more common ***bulletproof*** as a single word, but ***bomb-proof*** is more likely to be hyphenated.

But OP is primarily asking about *metaphoric* usages. On that front, there's no doubt at all that ***bulletproof*** is far more common...

> *a bulletproof argument* [- 280 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=Mk_PWtuPLIvPgAaphIfIBw&q=%22a%20bulletproof%20argument%22&oq=%22a%20bulletproof%20argument%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6671.6671.0.7563.1.1.0.0.0.0.73.73.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.eMCnOjLjMaQ) in Google Books
>    *a bullet-proof argument* [- 85 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20bullet%20proof%20argument%22) (including 2-word versions without hyphen)
>    *a bombproof argument* [- 2 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=P0_PWofOE4nQgAaWrJmwCQ&q=%22a%20bombproof%20argument%22&oq=%22a%20bombproof%20argument%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10373.10373.0.10569.1.1.0.0.0.0.81.81.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ncf0pvmimug)
>    *a bomb proof argument* [- 2 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=Mk_PWtuPLIvPgAaphIfIBw&q=%22a%20bomb%20proof%20argument%22&oq=%22a%20bomb%20proof%20argument%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3255.5390.0.5857.8.8.0.0.0.0.82.555.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.whxAek0bZPI)

---

Another extremely common metaphoric usage (for *arguments*, at least), is...

> *a **watertight** argument* [- 1920 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=Mk_PWtuPLIvPgAaphIfIBw&q=%22a%20watertight%20argument%22&oq=%22a%20watertight%20argument%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1453096.1458290.0.1459008.22.22.0.0.0.0.113.1562.20j1.21.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.hNcxMD23dXQ)

Focusing more specifically on OP's context, it's probably worth noting that Google Books claims 41 instances of [*a bulletproof program*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=oWXPWvqkGqWRgAa8pbOIDw&q=%22a%20bulletproof%20program%22&oq=%22a%20bulletproof%20program%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5862.11632.0.12140.21.17.0.0.0.0.96.1099.16.16.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.0.0....0.r-koV2wblHY), but there are only 2 hits for [*a bombproof program*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=rmXPWtedC6yPgAa83LvQDA&q=%22a%20bombproof%20program%22&oq=%22a%20bombproof%20program%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20175.23353.0.24546.8.8.0.0.0.0.87.575.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Ez2VYbEPynw).

---

One more point relating to the *XXXX-proof* construction is that ***bullet**-proof* in particular can have a far more general metaphoric meaning than non-native speakers might expect. Consider, for example,...

> 1: [*He's bombproof.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s%20bombproof%22) (relatively uncommon; 87 hits in Google Books)
>    2: [*He's bulletproof.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s%20bulletproof%22) (962 hits)

...where (ignoring a few possible *literal* contexts), #1 would always imply that metaphorical "bombs / missiles" cannot harm ***him***. But #2 is also often used to mean *He is reliable, He will not let you / us / someone else down* (i.e. - asserting that ***others*** can rest easy, rather than the subject himself).

Comment: I felt like **airtight** was much more common than **watertight**, though checking in with [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watertight%2Cairtight&year_start=1800&year_end=2000), it's only been since about 1985 that **airtight** has dominated.

Comment: @Canadian: Charting just the words ***airtight*** and ***watertight*** doesn't necessarily tell us much, since we've no idea which instances are metaphoric. But since I *vastly* prefer ***watertight*** metaphorically coupled to ***argument***, I [checked that specifically.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+watertight+argument%2Can+airtight+argument&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20watertight%20argument%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20airtight%20argument%3B%2Cc0) It seems both Brits *and* older people are on my side of that fence/pond! :)

Comment: That's a good point.  Switching to AmE in your search shows a definite preference for **airtight**, so this must be one of those [transpondian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transpondian) differences in usage.

Comment: In spite of the rare usage of "bomb-proof software" I think the term still has a specific meaning (how much it overlaps with the Spanish meaning is an open question).  "Bulletproof" is a far more common designation, because it's far less common to design something to be "bomb proof".  I'd say only OS kernel designers might venture into terminology like that.

Comment: @Darren: I am/was a software developer, and I watch stuff like [Black Hat talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8DjTcANBx0) on Youtube. And I don't think "bomb-proof software" really has any specific meaning. Stretching a point, maybe a "more-literal-than-usual" usage implying "software that can still function within a distributed framework where many nodes / servers have been taken out by military action". The important point is "bulletproof" is widely applicable even with the more general sense of "not prone to (internally-based) failure", as well as "resistant to (external) attack".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did not mean it specifically in the context of software development.  "Bomb proof" is simply less common of a phrase than "bulletproof" because it is a stronger choice of words.  I agree that bulletproof is the go-to phrase here in English in almost any conceivable situation (the inconceivability of a bomb attack being related to that term's rarity)

Comment: @Darren: oic. Sorry, I wasn't paying attention. Agreed - in more general (still relatively uncommon compared to ***bulletproof***) metaphoric usages, there are 81 GB hits for [***He's bombproof**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s+bombproof%22) Of which some may be "literal" anyway, but the others I'd expect to always imply *he can't be harmed by (metaphoric missile attacks)*. Whereas many of the 965 instances of [***he's bulletproof***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s+bulletproof%22) probably imply *he will not let you down / be found wanting*.

Comment: Another pretty common word that could work in some contexts is *foolproof*.

Comment: We say an argument *holds water*; I don't think I've ever heard it said that an argument *holds air*.

Comment: I'd rather have something airtight than watertight.

Answer (score 28):

"Fool proof" is popular in the USA, at least in the northeast.

Like, not even a fool could break it. It's fool proof.

Comment: "_Idiot_ proof" is the variant that sprang to my mind. :-)

Comment: Fool proof (which is sometimes written as foolproof) is also common in Britain.

Comment: "Foolproof" is probably the most widely-used, everyday (not business jargon or field-specific) idiom for this concept. Note that not everyone will understand exactly where this term comes from, though; I realized last week that one of my children thought the expression was "*full* proof".

Comment: I think foolproof has different connotations. A foolproof program prevents *you* from doing inadvertently silly, but might still crash under unusual conditions (e.g., the network connection disappears). A bomb-proof program would handle those conditions gracefully ("Connection disappeared? No problem--start saving the changes locally while we reconnect"), but still might let idiots do dumb things.

Comment: Fool proof, for me, is hard to mess up.  Not even a fool would have trouble using it.  Bullet proof, means it hard to attack, hard to break.  Fool proof aligns with easy of use, where as bullet proof suggests robustness.

Answer (score 21):

For software, you could use *bulletproof* if you wanted to emphasize how the system won't crash, or *idiot-proof* if you wanted to emphasize the strength of the user interfaces. However, it might be better to use one of the more commonly-used English adjectives in the industry: [**robust**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_(computer_science)).

Wikipedia says:

> Robustness is the ability of a computer system to cope with errors during execution and cope with erroneous input. Robust programming is a style of programming that focuses on handling unexpected termination and unexpected actions.

One [website](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/R/robust.html) says that robust software "does not break down easily or is not wholly affected by a single application failure."

In your paragraph, you could say:

> This software is robust.

It's not quite an idiom – but it might be the term you want.

A more general term (one that could be used for both software and, say, an automobile or a washing mashine) would be **reliable**.

Answer (score 17):

The other answers are quite good, but to give some more choices, I'll add **[rock solid](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/rock_solid)**.

> Unlikely to change, fail, or collapse.

[Example from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/security/library/s-tried/):

> The only path to secure software is to use established, rock-solid
>   cryptographic algorithms.

[Another example](https://books.google.com/books?id=PyBZ-FVZLIIC&pg=PA41&dq=software%20%22rock%20solid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIgP76k7XaAhWQFXwKHSQrClg4FBDoAQhEMAU#v=onepage&q=software%20%22rock%20solid%22&f=false):

> RME products are a nice step up and have a rock solid track record
>   that rivals the Digidesign interface lineup.

As a comparison to another answer,

> *a rock solid argument* [- 436 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=WYzPWqHZDOeE0wKBmLKQDQ&q=%22a%20rock-solid%20argument%22&oq=%22a%20rock-solid%20argument%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5582.5582.0.8602.1.1.0.0.0.0.46.46.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.s7uMWOz0YvQ) in Google Books

Comment: I actually think this is better than the accepted and higher voted answers, as it better reflects the _meaning_ of the original expression that the question references.  The other answers get caught in the literal translation of the phrase.

Answer (score -5):

- a bug-proof program
- a hacker-proof program

[hacker-proof](https://www.google.com/search?ei=BrXPWryYGYTK_QbjuK6AAg&q=%22hacker-proof%20program%22%20software&oq=%22hacker-proof%20program%22%20software&gs_l=psy-ab.3...50608.53984.0.54277.15.12.2.0.0.0.138.975.9j3.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.Zcyum3oElI8)

[bug-proof](https://www.google.com/search?ei=8LTPWuHVBouyggfs66PoAQ&q=%22bug-proof%20program%22%20software&oq=%22bug-proof%20program%22%20software&gs_l=psy-ab.3...14945.20248.0.20456.17.15.2.0.0.0.172.1168.13j2.15.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.8.520...33i160k1j33i21k1.0.7E2DZdKPemQ)

Of course, there are also metaphors as given by others answering this question. Mine are only for software. The others can be used elsewhere.

Comment: Bug-free is more common than bug-proof in this context of software development.

Comment: Of course, bug-free is what advertising blurbs often say. But the meanings are not the same. Waterproof and water free would not be the same thing. And we are discussing terms for proof, not free. Thank you.

Comment: "we are discussing terms for proof, not free"> No, we are not, we are discussing equivalent terms for 'bomb-proof', and 'bug-free' would be closer in meaning than 'bug-proof' is. Of course, neither of them are ways in which you should describe your software if you don't want to get sued when one of your users inevitably finds that there *are* bugs...

Comment: As you two have stated, I think that no software is bug-proof, but often it's sold as bug-free. Often -> bug-free. You can verify it googling. We are discussing possible equivalents to express: "I make a program and this passes all the tests". It fits as advertising. Thank you, Lambie.

Comment: @SeanBurton The term in Spanish is: a prueba de bombas, which is bomb-proof. Except as a metaphor, one would not say call software "bomb-proof" or "bullet-proof". And I was merely giving other terms with "proof" for software that might conceivably be used though not in the bullet points. The actual terms used to describe software that is well designed in bullet points are terms like ***reliable and resilient software***.  Robust is usually for a computing system, not for software per se. Resilient software (that responds to failure adequately). Software (acceptance) testing: resilience

Comment: In any case, no software advertising is going to say bullet-proof.

Comment: @Lambie - There you go again, saying "no" when you mean "few". _We feel our bulletproof software .. and transparency make us the best-in-class player in the EHR marketplace_ ([1](http://www.healthcareitnews.com/press-release/docpatientnetworks-doctations-receives-onc-atcb-20112012-certification)) _Beyond introducing our bulletproof software and unparalleled support services..._ ([2](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-our-competitors-sending-business-way-ryan-ancheta)) _Our bulletproof software applications are simple and easy to use!_ ([3](https://shop.liveviewgps.com/products/eld-obd-le))

Comment: @J.R. No, I mean that ***I would never*** use it. The CEO of Lauvers Business Systems does use that in a sentence on linkedin. It describes software for cash registers. Fine. I would never (me) ever use it. And that is just about the only one, I could find. There is, however, a company called BulletProof Software. That is a good name for software company.

Comment: I would not advise  using it. Especially, for a Spanish-speaking company trying to sound cool.

Comment: Unfortunately, "no software advertising is going to say bullet-proof" is not the same thing as, "I would never use the phrase bullet-proof" or "I would not advise using bullet-proof".